# strange command prompt error

Tags: command-line, bash, execute-command, syntax

Whenever I have two command prompts open I always get this script coming up after I execute the commands. 
Just to clarify the commands execute and output correctly but after the out put before the next command prompt I get this. does anyone know what it is and how to solve it

N.B. if I have more than two command prompts open it will still only appear in the second one not the third or forth just the second one

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: syntax error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: K
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ?
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: H
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print / 2
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Looks like you're piping something to `bc`. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: check ~/.bashrc, perhaps something's wrong there

Comment: hi @Jos could you please explain what bc is as I do not recognise it

Comment: hi @Putnik I have customised my command prompt I have double checked my bashrc file and it looks OK to me. However I will edit my question to include it in the question however if it was a problem with bashrc I would expect the problem to appear in all the terminals I created not just the 2nd one.

Comment: `bc` (see `man bc`) is the *bash calculator*, a utility for doing complex calculations in bash scripts. In fact, if you do `echo K | bc` you will get exactly the above error messages, so I wondered whether you have a `| bc` somewhere in your .bashrc, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by changing the PS1 in my .bashrc file from

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[1;4;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[0;34m\]Date:\d | Time:\t\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[2;33m\]Shell:\s | Version:\V\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[4;1;31m\]CPU Usage $(echo print `top -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d$" " -f10 | tail -n +8 | head -n -1 | paste -sd+ | bc`/ `nproc` | python)% | Free Memory $(awk "/MemFree/{print \$2}" /proc/meminfo)\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[4;35m\]Command History:\!\[\e[00m\] | \[\e[4;37m\]Command Number:\#\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[1;33m\]{Directory:\w}\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[1;2;32m\]I am ready for your commands master \$}-\[\e[00m\]\[\e[36m\]'
```

to

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\e[1;4;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[0;34m\]Date:\d | Time:\t\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[2;33m\]Shell:\s | Version:\V\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[4;1;31m\]CPU Usage $(echo print `top -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d$" " -f10 | tail -n +8 | head -n -1 | paste -sd+ | bc`/ `nproc` | python)% | Free Memory $(awk "/MemFree/{print \$2}" /proc/meminfo)\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[4;35m\]Command History:\!\[\e[00m\] | \[\e[4;37m\]Command Number:\#\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[1;33m\]{Directory:\w}\[\e[00m\]\n\[\e[1;2;32m\]I am ready for your commands master \$}-\[\e[00m\]\[\e[36m\]'
```

however if anyone can tell me what was wrong with the first PS1 then that would be greatly appreciated